# How to solve mouseenter/mouseleave issues

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I need help in solving some mouseenter/mouseleave issues.
Here's a visual schematic:

[image: Schematic]

So, there's this vertical buttons slider. When you click any of these buttons, a "lightbox" div pops-up along with a background white div, overlapping the slider container. If I click the lightbox div again, it closes and everything returns to the default state. The problem is that the button's mouseenter/mouseleave events are getting in the way, causing some issues.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
function rocksType_mouseEvents_run(){

    // Mouseenter events
    $('.rocksType_DBitems_container').on('mouseenter', '> div:not(.rocksType_highlighted)', function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({'width':'116px', 'height':'109px', 'left':'0%', 'right':'4%', 'margin-top':'1.2%', 'margin-bottom':'1.2%'}, 300, 'swing')
      .find('p', this).stop().animate({'font-size':'110%', 'color':'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'}, 100, 'swing');
    });

    // Mouseleave events
    $('.rocksType_DBitems_container').on('mouseleave', '> div:not(.rocksType_highlighted)', function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({'width':'106px', 'height':'99px', 'left':'4%', 'right':'4%', 'margin-top':'5.2%', 'margin-bottom':'5.1%'}, 300, 'swing')
      .find('p', this).stop().animate({'font-size':'100%', 'color':'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}, 100, 'swing');
    });

    // Click events
    $('.rocksType_DBitems_container').on('click', '> div:not(.rocksType_highlighted)', function(){

      // De-highlight currently rocksType_highlighted item
      function dehighlight_clickedRocksType(){
        $('.rocksType_DBitems_container > div.rocksType_highlighted').removeClass('rocksType_highlighted').stop().animate({'width':'106px', 'height':'99px', 'left':'4%', 'right':'4%', 'margin-top':'5.2%', 'margin-bottom':'5.2%'}, 300, 'swing')
        .find('p').stop().animate({'font-size':'73%'}, 150, 'swing',
          function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({'width':'100px', 'height':'93px', 'left':'5%', 'right':'5%', 'margin-top':'7.6%', 'margin-bottom':'7.6%', 'opacity':'0.3'}, 300, 'swing')
            .find('p').stop().animate({'font-size':'100%', 'color':'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'}, 150, 'swing');
          }
        );
      }

      // De-highlight currently rocksType_highlighted item
      dehighlight_clickedRocksType();

      // Highlight clicked item
      $(this).addClass('rocksType_highlighted').stop().animate({'width':'100px', 'height':'93px', 'left':'5%', 'right':'5%', 'margin-top':'7.6%', 'margin-bottom':'7.6%'}, 300, 'swing')
      .find('p').stop().animate({'font-size':'73%'}, 300, 'swing',
        function(){
          $(this).stop().animate({'font-size':'110%', 'color':'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'}, 300, 'swing')
          .parent().stop().animate({'width':'116px', 'height':'109px', 'left':'0%', 'right':'4%', 'margin-top':'1.3%', 'margin-bottom':'1.3%', 'opacity':'1'}, 300, 'swing',
            function(){
              $('.rocksType_DBitem_lightbox').fadeIn(1000);
              $('.rocksType_lightboxBackground').fadeIn(1000);
              $('.rocksType_DBitem_lightbox').one('click', function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(300);
                $('.rocksType_lightboxBackground').fadeOut(300);
                // De-highlight currently rocksType_highlighted item
                dehighlight_clickedRocksType();
              });
            }
          );
        }
      );

    });

  }

  rocksType_mouseEvents_run();
```

... and a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xk6p9/).

Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: add event.stopPropagation() to your event handlers.

Comment: That way the buttons will only mouseenter/mouseleave once...

Comment: use .off() to toggle mouse events, with some state variable

Comment: I could use some help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/crEHc/1/
Took the div for the lightbox outisde the container , and found a typo one("click"....
instead of on("click"...

```
$('.rocksType_DBitem_lightbox').one('click', function(){
```

Comment: Apparently, taking the div out is enough. Thanx!